# How can i call a flowLayoutPanel to remove a button control via name, that was is nested inside that same flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

```
class RTB
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    Button bt = new Button();
    RichTextBox r = new RichTextBox();  

    public RichTextBox addPanel(string Task)
    { 
        bt.Text = "X";    
        bt.Click += new EventHandler(btnButton_Click);
        r.Controls.Add(bt);
        return r;
    }
    
    void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f.rem(r.Name);
    }

}

class Form1 : Form
{
    public void rem(string name)  
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveByKey(name);
    }
}
```

In the `RTB` class, I am creating a RichRextBox, that contains a button control, and adding the Richtexbox with the button straight into a `FlowLayoutPanel`,

the button is subscribed to `btnButton_Click` so when it is clicked it will run `f.rem(r.Name)`.

now when I click the button inside the `RichTextBox` to remove it from the `FlowLayoutPanel` it doesn't work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** I am able to create and add them to the `FlowLayoutPanel`, I did not include that code because i think it is irrelevant to this specific problem.

Comment: Forgot to add 'f' in 'f.rem(r.Name)' is Form1 f = new Form1();

Comment: Where did `f` come from?  Most likely you've declared `Form1 f =  new Form1()` in your `rtb` class.  This is not the same form as the one you're seeing on your screen, thus your problem.  But what "name" are you trying to use to remove the control with?  You haven't assigned anything to the `.Name` property of your RTB...

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign name for `RichTextBox` that you need to remove at create

```
   RichTextBox r = new RichTextBox();
   r.Name = "Any_Unique_Name";
```

or other way without use `ram` function :

```
   void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //delete parent of clicked `Button` will be target `RichTextBox`
       ((Button)sender).Parent.Dispose();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `r` variable available to you in the button click handler.  You can simplify even more with an anonymous handler:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler((s, e) => {
    r.Dispose();
});
```

Now the control will disappear when the button is clicked.